# WARNING: Module ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, php-extension, php-7.1

I am trying to run comoper require, but these errors are occurs. I tried all these solution but I can't get a solution for me.

[Module pdo_mysql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640722/module-pdo-mysql-ini-file-doesnt-exist-under-etc-php-7-0-mods-available)

[How to check which PHP extensions have been enabled/disabled in Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351260/how-to-check-which-php-extensions-have-been-enabled-disabled-in-ubuntu-linux-12)

[WARNING: Module ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717174/warning-module-ini-file-doesnt-exist-under-etc-php-7-0-mods-available)

```
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-recode.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tidy.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
        - /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
      You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

root@ahmad:/var/www/htdocs/www.dukanstation.com# sudo phpenmod mysqlnd.ini
WARNING: Module mysqlnd.ini ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
WARNING: Module mysqlnd.ini ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
WARNING: Module mysqlnd.ini ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module mysqlnd.ini ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module mysqlnd.ini ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available
```

Comment: Check this thread if it works for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717174/warning-module-ini-file-doesnt-exist-under-etc-php-7-0-mods-available

Comment: mo its not works.

Comment: What version of php are You trying to set up ? I see errors related to both `7.1` and `7.3`. To enable specific module You first need to download it `sudo apt install php7.3-zip` and then enable it `sudo phpenmod zip`. You need to do this for every listed module.

Comment: Thanks for answering..Resolved.